# Get interval to last UTC midnight from an NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I need to compare two times, but one is the current `NSDate` and the other is an `NSTimeInterval`. I need to trigger an action when the current time interval since the last UTC midnight gets **larger** than the given time interval. I'm happy with simply

```
NSDate *rightNowUTC = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

to get current UTC `NSDate`, but I need to strip it down to "the time interval between whatever *now is and the last time midnight UTC occurred".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSCalendar` provides a method to get the start of the day (midnight) for a given date:

```
NSDate *rightNowUTC = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *midnight = [NSCalendar.currentCalendar startOfDayForDate: rightNowUTC];
NSTimeInterval interval = [rightNowUTC timeIntervalSinceDate: midnight];
```

Comment: That did it. I was really close to finding a long way around to the same effect as startOfDayForDate. Didn't know about that function. Thanks a ton @vadian.